# @DefaultValue is not compatible with @PathParameter in RESTful framework

Tags: java, rest

I got a requirement that I need a default value for a `@PathParameter`.

And this is how my code looks like:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/family/{member}")
    public Response responseMsg( @DefaultValue("Father") @PathParam("member")  String pathParameter) {}
```

The compiler will not show any error, and also the application of course will not act the way like what I've expected.

because the uri "/family/`null`" will not match the Path "`/family/{member}`" but "`/family/`"

May I know if there is any way to assign a default value for a `@PathParam` and how?
and also I want to know if  `@DefaultValue` only compatible with  `@QueryParameter`?

Comment: URI should be, by definition, unique - and default values would contradict this paradigm because you could not distinctly say which resource answers which URI when omitting parts of the URI and replacing them with implicit default values.

Comment: Thanks Smutje for pointing out **URI should be, by definition, unique**

Comment: but the java doc for jax-rs also mention: it can defines the default value of request metadata that is bound using one of the following annotations: **PathParam**, QueryParam, MatrixParam, CookieParam, FormParam, or HeaderParam. The default value is used if the corresponding metadata is not present in the request. see [link](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.1.GA/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html)

Comment: Javadoc is buggy for that. Please see https://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/users/archive/2012-03/message/100 But the JAX-RS 1.1 specification (from JCP Appendix A) is correct: 'DefaultValue: Specifies a default value for a field, property or method
parameter annotated with QueryParam,
MatrixParam, CookieParam, FormParam or
HeaderParam. The specified value will be used if the
corresponding query or matrix parameter is not present in
the request URI, if the corresponding form parameter is
not in the request entity body, or if the corresponding
HTTP header is not included in the request.'

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best practice here will be to redirect from the method annotated with `@Path("/family/")` to the method you have shown with the desired default value:

```
@GET
@Path("/family")
public Response redirectingMethod() {
    return responseMsg("Father");
}
```

Comment: but Path("/family") also in used for pointing to another resources, lets say the whole family member list.

Comment: OK. So there is no solution for you problem as far as I can tell without changing the URLs scheme in your application